# Copy and paste text by using mouse, just as the functionality works in Unix

Tags: macos, mac, unix, terminal, mouse

I am a Unix user, and I am new to Mac. I am so used to copying text on Unix by just clicking the left mouse button and then pasting it by simply clicking the right mouse button. However, in the Terminal application on Mac, I have to select the text using mouse pointer and then <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste it.

Can someone please let me know if there is a similar option on a Mac?

Comment: I generally highlight the text, RMB, and select "copy".  Or highlight and use Cmd-C.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [iTerm 2](http://iterm2.com) you can set it to copy to clipboard on text selection.

[image: settings screenshot]

It will however still mean you need to right click -> paste or cmd+v to paste your selection.

Alternatively you can install [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org) and a graphic terminal of your choosing.